# Is there a way to define a MongoDB schema using Motor?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado-motor, motordriver

There is a way to define MongoDB collection schema using mongoose in NodeJS. Mongoose verifies the schema at the time of running the queries.

I have been unable to find a similar thing for Motor in Python/Tornado. Is there a way to achieve a similar effect in Motor, or is there a package which can do that for me?

Comment: See [`odmatic`](https://github.com/art049/odmantic/) as a possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. Motor is a MongoDB driver, it does basic operations but doesn't provide many conveniences. An Object Document Mapper (ODM) library like MongoTor, built on Motor, provides higher-level features like schema validation.

I don't vouch for MongoTor. Proceed with caution. Consider whether you really need an ODM: mongodb's raw data format is close enough to Python types that most applications don't need a layer between their code and the driver.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (2019) this project Umongo https://github.com/Scille/umongo seems the more active and usefull if you need a sync/async Python MongoDB ODM. It work with multiple drivers like PyMongo or Motor for async.
Doc is here: http://umongo.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [ODMantic](https://art049.github.io/odmantic/) as it has the best documentation and the engine supports motor client.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (2023), Beanie [[Github Link]](https://github.com/roman-right/beanie) is the best ODM I have ever used. It works beautifully with FASTAPI and is deeply integrated with Pydantic making it very easy to model data models.

They have a very nice documentation given in [here](https://beanie-odm.dev/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: looks interesting, why do you recommend to use it? instead to use only pydantic + motor

Comment: As mentioned. Its batteries included and its easy to work with. Furthermore, If you want to use the underlying Motor drivers, you can do so by getting an `AsyncIOMotorClient` instance and get a `AsyncIOMotorClientSession` from that and pass the session directly into the ODM models. I especially love this a lot as it allows me to update multiple documents using transactions which currently (at the time of writing) - no ODM supports for python.